# How do I unset a background in gnome on the command line?

Tags: command-line, gnome

So someone decided to set my gnome background as a practical joke to a rather disturbing picture. However, I don't use gnome and only log into it by accident. I need to remove the picture so when I accidently log into gnome it's not there. Can someone tell me what part of what file to modify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/gnome/background/picture_options scaled # background style
gconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename PATHTOIMAGEHERE # background file
```